# how to find out validation error in jsf2

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i have one **.xhtml** file in which i have 2 `form`s one updating another, when i submit 2nd form having id `allOfficesLink_form` form is not submitting i didn't get any error, i dont know where is the error?

```
 <!-- p:message outside form -->
<p:messages id="globalId_messages" autoUpdate="true" />
 <!-- p:message outside form -->

<h:form >
//this is not actual code
//some input fields
//ajax command button which is updating id="allOfficesLink_form"
<p:commandButton
update=":#{p:component('companyId_select')} :#{p:component('allOffices_link')} :#{p:component('allOfficesLink_form')}">
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="allOfficesLink_form">
<h:commandLink id="allOffices_link"
styleClass="link_general"
disabled="#{budgetScenarioFormationBudgetAllocationAction.budgetFinancialYearBean.modBean != 'OF'}"
value="[all offices]"
>
<f:ajax listener="#{budgetScenarioFormationBudgetAllocationAction.getSubHeadOfAccountsOfAllOffices()}" />
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too see validation messages you can either include a `h:message` tag for each input component, or add a `h:messages`, which will show validation messages for all components in the form. if you are using ajax to make the submit, make sure to also update the submitting form so that messages are displayed.
in your case, however, the 2nd form doesn't have any input so there's no way it's a validation error (unless you omitted part of the code). how do you know it's a validation error?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my question by removing `:#{p:component('allOfficesLink_form')}"` from `update` attribute but i dont understand why i was getting this issue?

```
<p:commandButton
update=":#{p:component('companyId_select')} :#{p:component('allOffices_link')} >
</p:commandButton>
```